# Android Navigation Drawer Layout throws an error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

Drawer Layout uses two Relative Layout, throws an error as:

xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="197.50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#2f2f2f"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:listSelector="#2FB3E3" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/build"
                style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="100dp"
                android:text="My View"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> 02-18 09:22:53.649: E/AndroidRuntime(30768):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

```
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items

             boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

            if () {
            --------    
            } else {
            --------    
            }
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

It throwa error as  " InvocationTargetException "  line is

boolean drawerOpen=mDrawerlayout

Comment: its an error of imports, please use proper imports.

Comment: once now check is pasted xml code also , what kind of proper imports

Comment: see, you are try to put layout param of `RelativeLayout` to `DrawerLayout` some where in your code so correct this

Comment: In DrawerLayout i want textview at bottom

Comment: but where is your `DrawerLayout `

Answer (score 0):

Try

`boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(Gravity.START);`

instead of

`boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);`

Also , I dont see any `NavigationDrawer` in your xml. Make sure tat you have one.

You should have `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout />` as your parent tag

**UPDATE**

Now you dont have the view to display without drawerlayout,  you should write a `FrameLayout` that holds  the normal items to be displayed without drawer.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem has cropped up in my code. This is my code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".HomeActivity"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/item_width"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Left drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/theDrawerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/windowBackgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/theDrawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#FFF"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawerLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/theDrawer"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="imagen"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:longClickable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Left drawer -->

<!-- Right drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/theDrawerRight"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/windowBackgroundColor"/>
<!-- Right drawer -->
```

And when I executed that line:

```
mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

the app crashed. So what's the trick? passing to closeDrawer the parameter which contains your most outter RelativeLayout which contains the List shown in the drawer (the drawer itself). So that the code remains that way:

```
mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
```

That isn't crashing.